# Visual Studio Name Mangling "YAPEAV" and Mysql connector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mysql-connector, name-mangling

I'm getting unresolved external symbol error when linking my code with MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.0.
Here's the error message:

```
6>database.lib(db_manager.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
"class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
referenced in function "class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance(void)" (?get_mysql_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
```

I used `dumpbin` to get a list of symbols in the mysqlconn-static.lib and found a similar symbol:

```
COMDAT; sym= "class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPEAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
```

When these two lines are lined up, the difference looks like:

```
(?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPEAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)  
(?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)
```

What is the difference in Name Managling between `YAPEAV` AND `YAPAV`?

I have an idea that my issue is related to incompatiblities between the MySQL Connector library and how I'm building my code.

I searched the web and found a bug against MySQL Connector 1.1.0, but it was changed to "not a bug".

I am using Visual Studio 2010 compiling to a 32-bit target using a 64-bit platform.
The MySQL Connector C++ is version 1.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSVC tool `undname` is your friend.  Using it, you find that

- `?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPEAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ` corresponds to:

  ```
  class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __ptr64 __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)
  ```
- `?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ` corresponds to:

  ```
  class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)
  ```

The difference being a `__ptr64` decoration.  It seems like you're building a 32-bit program but linking against a library built for a 64-bit target.

Comment: Many thanks.  Sounds about right since my development environment is 64-bit.  Now to get the 32-bit version of the library. :-)